# XML Parsing Error: no element found while loading application page

Tags: application-pages, xml, parser-error

I have added an application Page (MyCertificate.aspx) which generates PDF file by using Crystal Reports into an existing SharePoint solution. Everything works fine on my development server but after deploying to Test environment, IE and Chrome did not show any thing, but Firefox throws this error:

```
XML Parsing Error: no element found
Location: https://MyPortal/MyPage/_layouts/15/results/MyCertificate.aspx?spid=ENG&pid=12

Line Number 1, Column 1:
```

The thing is, its a pretty big solution (which contains many application pages) but everything works fine except the Page: `MyCertificate.aspx` and every thing works fine on development server.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is, you must have same crystal report version installed on both environments, i.e on test and development. it will fix the problem